# Finding all integers $m$ and $n$ satisfying $\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics

So my older brother posed this question to me and I've been stuck on it for a long time.

> Find all integers $m$ and $n$ that satisfy
> $$\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{100}$$

(He actually said a $2$ digit multiple of $3$ instead of $100$ but...yea.)

So this is what I have so far:

1. multiply both sides by $mn100:$ so then $100n-100m=mn$
2. try to factor $n(100-m)-100m=0.$ And that is where I'm stuck. I know $SFFT$ (Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick) but it doesn't seem to work here no matter what I subtract.

Can I please have a hint as to what to add or subtract? Thank you!

Comment: This user is asking questions from a test for a math summer camp. awesomemath.org. His history of questions are from that test with slightly altered numbers. Please refrain from answering them until the test is over. (march 27 2022)